# Given an unsigned 32 bit integer, count the number of occurrences of pattern

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, pattern-matching, bit-manipulation

I want to calculate how many times num2 came in num1.
Both numbers can be a maximum of 32 bits.

Given an unsigned 32 bit integer, count the number of occurrences of pattern 101(can be up to 32 bit ) (Write a program using bitwise operations only)
these no. can be up to 32 bits

100101 --> 1 time
​1010110101-->4 times

this code work for string not optimal for binary no.

```
uint32_t ReturnCount(string num1,string num2) {
            int n = num1.length(); int m = num2.length();
            int count=0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n-m ; ++i) 
            {
                    int j ;
                    for (j=0; j < m; ++j) 
                    {
                        if (num1[i + j] != num2[j]) 
                            break;
                    }
                    if (j == m) 
                    {
                     count ++;
                     j=0;
                    }  
             }
          return count;        
        }
```

Comment: `num2.length()` a `uint32_t` has no length()

Comment: If it works for strings but not numbers, try converting the numbers into strings first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the possible ways.

1. Use [std::bit_width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width) to calculate the width of `num1` and `mum2`.
2. If the width of `num1` is less that width of `num2` - no matches.
3. Create a mask of the width of `num2`

```cpp
    uint32_t mask = (1 << width) - 1;
```

4. Start matching in a loop:

```cpp
    if(num2 == (num1 & mask)) // found a match
```

5. Shift both `num2` and `mask` left by one
6. If number of shifts (5) is greater than the difference in width between `num1` and `num2` - you are done.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for editing! I was surprised that my indentation didn't work :(

Comment: Lists, numbered or points, prevent the indentation from being seen as a request for code formatting. Instead it seems to be a request to indent as text inline with the list's text. If I was a bit more on the ball I would have surrounded the code with single backticks since the code's just one-liners, but such is life.

Comment: @VladFeinstein      bit_width (num1) or  bit_width (num2)   return the no. of bits required to  represent these num .
But I know those are binary num can be upto 32 bits  consisted of 0/1. so both width can be upto 32. 
 I want to get no. of bits present in 0101001 ..... stream.
        std::cout << "bit_width= " << std::bit_width(x) << '\n';